# Spring Integration - TCP outbound gateway - Getting connection reset error

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I am getting the connection reset error in just one environment. Below is the SI settings file I am using right now. It works 50% of the time. As you could imagine, the response from the destination doesn't reach the AbstractByteArraySerializer implementation.

I don't understand what's resetting the connection. Kindly share your thoughts on how to get rid of the error.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
xmlns:int-ip="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/ip"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/ip http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/ip/spring-integration-ip.xsd">



<int:gateway id="gw" service-interface=" com.myGateway"
    default-request-channel="objectOut" />

<int:channel id="objectOut" />

<int-ip:tcp-connection-factory id="client"
    type="client" host="host"  port=9000 single-use="true" so-timeout="30000" using-nio="false" so-keep-alive="true" 
    serializer="customDSerializer" deserializer="customDSerializer" />
<bean id="customDSerializer" class="com.CustomSerializerDeserializer">
    <property name="maxMessageSize" value="4096" />
</bean>

<int-ip:tcp-outbound-gateway id="outGateway"
    request-channel="objectOut" reply-channel="toSA" connection-factory="client"
    request-timeout="30000" reply-timeout="30000"/>

<int:service-activator input-channel="toSA"
    ref="partService" method="handleResponse"/>

<bean id="partService" class="com.PartService"/>

<int:channel id="toSA" />
<int:channel id="bytesIn" />

</beans>
```

**Error from application log:**

```
org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: error occurred in message handler [org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.TcpOutboundGateway#0]; nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Exception while awaiting reply; nested exception is java.net.SocketException: Connection reset, failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=V013   000802106048                         202011240010, headers={replyChannel=org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel@58bc60ee, errorChannel=org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel@58bc60ee, id=b2fe03e4-32a5-d773-9cff-ded5e38490a8, timestamp=1606198257312}]
    at org.springframework.integration.support.utils.IntegrationUtils.wrapInHandlingExceptionIfNecessary(IntegrationUtils.java:189)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:179)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:115)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:133)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:106)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:73)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:460)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:401)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:187)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSendAndReceive(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:233)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSendAndReceive(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessagingTemplate.sendAndReceive(AbstractMessagingTemplate.java:46)
    at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.sendAndReceive(MessagingTemplate.java:97)
    at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.sendAndReceive(MessagingTemplate.java:38)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessagingTemplate.convertSendAndReceive(AbstractMessagingTemplate.java:96)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessagingTemplate.convertSendAndReceive(AbstractMessagingTemplate.java:86)
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.MessagingGatewaySupport.doSendAndReceive(MessagingGatewaySupport.java:493)
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.MessagingGatewaySupport.sendAndReceive(MessagingGatewaySupport.java:466)
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean.invokeGatewayMethod(GatewayProxyFactoryBean.java:527)
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean.doInvoke(GatewayProxyFactoryBean.java:470)
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean.invoke(GatewayProxyFactoryBean.java:461)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy564.send(Unknown Source)
    at com.pip.services.pipService(PartService.java:262)
    at com.pip.services.PartService.sendReqload(PartService.java:166)
    at com.pip.services.PartService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$68f2c764.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:294)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.adapter.AfterReturningAdviceInterceptor.invoke(AfterReturningAdviceInterceptor.java:55)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.adapter.MethodBeforeAdviceInterceptor.invoke(MethodBeforeAdviceInterceptor.java:56)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:93)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688)
    at com.pip.services.PartService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$782f05a1.createAndSendInquiryReqPayload(<generated>)
    at com.pip.services.PartService.addItemToCart(PartService.java:639)
    at com.pip.services.PartService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$576fe592.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:294)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.adapter.AfterReturningAdviceInterceptor.invoke(AfterReturningAdviceInterceptor.java:55)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.adapter.MethodBeforeAdviceInterceptor.invoke(MethodBeforeAdviceInterceptor.java:56)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:93)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688)
    at com.pip.services.PartService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$79bbaceb.addItemToCart(<generated>)
    at com.pip.controller.PartController.partAdd(PartController.java:191)
    at com.pip.controller.PartController$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$843b359d.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.adapter.AfterReturningAdviceInterceptor.invoke(AfterReturningAdviceInterceptor.java:55)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.adapter.MethodBeforeAdviceInterceptor.invoke(MethodBeforeAdviceInterceptor.java:56)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.adapter.AfterReturningAdviceInterceptor.invoke(AfterReturningAdviceInterceptor.java:55)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.adapter.MethodBeforeAdviceInterceptor.invoke(MethodBeforeAdviceInterceptor.java:56)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.adapter.MethodBeforeAdviceInterceptor.invoke(MethodBeforeAdviceInterceptor.java:56)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:93)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688)
    at com.pip.controller.PartController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$eced7dad.partAdd(<generated>)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1873.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:189)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:800)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1038)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:908)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:652)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter.handleNonCORS(CorsFilter.java:352)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter.doFilter(CorsFilter.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:666)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:690)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:373)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.Nio2Endpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(Nio2Endpoint.java:1674)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.processSocket(AbstractEndpoint.java:1104)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.Nio2Endpoint$Nio2SocketWrapper$2.completed(Nio2Endpoint.java:598)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.Nio2Endpoint$Nio2SocketWrapper$2.completed(Nio2Endpoint.java:576)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SecureNio2Channel$1.completed(SecureNio2Channel.java:969)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SecureNio2Channel$1.completed(SecureNio2Channel.java:898)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Invoker.invokeUnchecked(Invoker.java:127)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Invoker$2.run(Invoker.java:219)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.AsynchronousChannelGroupImpl$1.run(AsynchronousChannelGroupImpl.java:112)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Exception while awaiting reply; nested exception is java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.TcpOutboundGateway$AsyncReply.getReply(TcpOutboundGateway.java:352)
    at org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.TcpOutboundGateway.handleRequestMessage(TcpOutboundGateway.java:159)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:123)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:169)
    ... 124 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:186)
    at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:140)
    at com.pip.CustomSerializerDeserializer.read(CustomSerializerDeserializer.java:118)
    at com.pip.CustomSerializerDeserializer.deserialize(CustomSerializerDeserializer.java:98)
    at com.pip.CustomSerializerDeserializer.deserialize(CustomSerializerDeserializer.java:50)
    at org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.TcpNetConnection.getPayload(TcpNetConnection.java:124)
    at org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.TcpMessageMapper.toMessage(TcpMessageMapper.java:176)
    at org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.TcpMessageMapper.toMessage(TcpMessageMapper.java:63)
    at org.springframework.integration.mapping.InboundMessageMapper.toMessage(InboundMessageMapper.java:40)
    at org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.TcpNetConnection.run(TcpNetConnection.java:180)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    ... 1 more
```

Comment: You need to consult with the server side to see a reason why they reset connection from you.

Comment: @ArtemBilan Tried checking that but did not find any trace in the server logs. The server side claims to be returning the response. Is there anything specific that we should be looking for in the server side?

Comment: https://www.pico.net/kb/what-is-a-tcp-reset-rst - you can use a network monitor such as WireShark to see the `RST` but it probably won't help you figure out why the server is closing the socket.